# How to write "потому что"?

Tags: пунктуация

I am totally confused in how I should write "потому что". There could be at least 4 possible options:

1) потому что

2) потому, что

3) по тому что

4) по тому, что

As far as I can tell, there should be a comma placed in this  case:

> Он просто ходил по брусу - **по тому, что** ещё его дед где-то отыскал и
>   приволок в этот "спортивный зал".

and, perhaps, no comma is needed here:

> -- Почему вы отказались сотрудничать с нами?
>
> -- Да **потому что** у вас всё перевёрнуто с ног на голову!

but I am not sure.

Can anyone provide an overview of the relevant rules here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only numbers (1), (2) and (4) are correct; the number (3) is incorrect. Your post provides perfect example sentences to illustrate both cases.

The basic rule about commas before "что" is that you need one in all cases except when "что" is a part of an indivisible compound expression, such as "во что бы то ни стало", "потому что", and so on.

"потому что" is a *compound subordinating conjunction* (составной подчинительный союз). It is a single part of speech, so normally you should not separate its two parts with a comma. "по-" in "потому" is not a separate word, it is a *prefix*, so it is written together with "-тому".

"по тому", on the other hand, is a *preposition* (предлог) followed by a demonstrative pronoun (указательное местоимение). The word "что", a *conjunction* (изъяснительный союз), is a separate word, so the basic rule applies, i.e. you need a comma.

Using number (2) is an advanced subject. Consider these two comma placements:

> Он ей нравился, потому что был очень мужественным.

and

> Он ей нравился потому, что был очень мужественным.

Both sentences translate roughly as

> She liked him, because he was very courageous.

The difference is that placing the comma before "потому" stresses the the consequence (i.e. the fact that she liked him), while placing the comma before "что" stresses the cause (i.e. the fact that he was courageous). This is called "расчленение союза" (splitting up the conjunction), and it is a somewhat non-trivial subject. You can read more about it [here](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.31).

Comment: I know that number 2) can also be used, it's the same as number 1). Examples can also be added to your othewise excellent answer.

Comment: @YellowSky Thank you very much, it took me a while to construct a decent example for the #2. I edited the answer to show how the conjunction can be split.

Comment: @YellowSky - I kind of come to realize now that #3 ("**по тому что**") can also be correct in some, perhaps, rare cases: "На этой стройке у них было только два железнодорожных пути: вот этот, на котором мы стоим, и вон тот. По этому возили только щебень, а вот **по тому что** только не возили! И щебень, и кирпичи, и цемент, и даже дрова", or "Я понимаю, что ты ещё боишься идти по этому брусу, но вот **по тому что** тебе стоит пройтись?", or "Хорошо, по этому делу ты кое-что нам сообщил, а **по тому что** у тебя есть?"

Comment: @brilliant I am very tempted to put a dash in front of "что" in all three sentences from your last comment. The difference between these sentences and the ones where a comma is necessary is that the word "что" is used as an interrogative pronoun ("what"), rather than a conjunction ("that").

Comment: I don't think it's an interrogative pronoun in "что только не возили!" The usage of a dash is possible here, however, it's not mandatory - all three cases will be absolutely correct without a dash. Whether or not the dash should be placed is often indicated by the change in intonation or by a pause in  spoken speech. I personally don't feel any significant change in intonation or anything like a pause in the third case: "Хорошо, по этому делу ты кое-что нам сообщил, а **по тому что** у тебя есть?"